# Offline Reward System in my Java application

Tags: java, android

I'm building a simple clicker game, so far it's going very nice with all help from this forum and you guys from my previous questions.

Okey so I have a variable called **money_persecond** and its set to *one*, basically every one second you get *one* coin, according to **money_persecond**.
How could I make a system that counts the time the application is closed and when the user opens the application again, it gonna multiply the seconds that application were closed by **money_persecond**, making a simple Offline Reward System?

Comment: do you have any code?

Comment: If GPS is an option for you then use its timebase for reasons that @Binarynam mentions.  (Location.getTime() which in theory is the satellite-sourced time which can be used for arithmetic.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the app opens/exits, you can store the timestamp somewhere (db, encrypted/protected/hidden flat config file) and compare values accordingly.

However such a solution is far from ideal. Without an internet connexion and some kind of server/Web Service you will have to rely on the client's time, allowing him to change it and cheat the system.

Comment: If worried about the application crashing/exiting abnormally, it could periodically update the exit time while open

Comment: Indeed, that would make it more viable.

Comment: Yes, thank you. I won't do any Offline Reward system until I actually get some server/web service with a clock or something to count time or something. Thanks for help :P